# ¿Como puedo ejecutar la siguiente consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero poder obtener el nombre de los meses extrayendo el mes de un campo que se llama`FECHA_RECIBE`pero en la consola de MySql me dice que hay un error cerca del`FROM`. el resto de la consulta funciona correctamente. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(VALOR) as costos CASE
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 1 THEN 'Enero'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 2 THEN 'Febrero'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 3 THEN 'Marzo'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 4 THEN 'Abril'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 5 THEN 'Mayo'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 6 THEN 'Junio'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 7 THEN 'Julio'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 8 THEN 'Agosto'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 9 THEN 'Septiembre'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 10 THEN 'Octubre'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
WHEN MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = 12 THEN 'Diciembre'
FROM huawei_combustible WHERE YEAR(FECHA_RECIBE) = '2017' AND 
MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = '12' AND DAY(FECHA_RECIBE) = '20' AND CIUDAD = 'CALI'
```

Comment: Creo que es correcto, te falta el END antes del FROM por que no veo el final del CASE ó podrias probar hacer un case para sacar el nombre de cada mes.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me sigue generando error, me dice que esta cerca del primer `WHEN`

Comment: te faltan comas y te faltan los finales de cada CASE, es decir estas haciendo una subconsulta la cual le diste el nombre de alias de costos eso debe de estar dentro de una funcion de agregacion y despues te falta un case para cada mes.

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta por favor para explicarme como hacerlo. te agradezco tu ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes simplificar tu consulta significativamente usando [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), indicando que te dé el nombre del mes con `%M`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(VALOR) as costos,
    DATE_FORMAT(FECHA_RECIBE, '%M') as mes
FROM huawei_combustible 
    WHERE YEAR(FECHA_RECIBE) = '2017' 
    AND MONTH(FECHA_RECIBE) = '12' 
    AND DAY(FECHA_RECIBE) = '20' 
    AND CIUDAD = 'CALI';
```

Si te saca los meses en inglés, puedes cambiarlo con [`SET lc_time_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html) para establecer (temporal o definitivamente) las **salidas** de fechas en castellano.

Comment: Bien, funciona correctamente pero no puedo pasarlo al español

Comment: @AnderssonViveros si antes de la consulta ejecutas por ejemplo: `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';` te lo mostrará en castellano.

Comment: Ya, agradezco tu ayuda, útil y practica la consulta de esta forma